# Code runs differently on different hardware

Tags: opengl, fluid-sim

I wrote a 2D fluid-solver in OpenGL ([code here](https://github.com/nilspin/SDL_OpenGL_Project)) some time back.

While it runs flawlessly on my onboard Intel GPU,

[image: when running on Intel GPU]

the simulation very quickly "blows-up" when same code is run using nvidia card :

[image: mere half a second into the program]

In the second picture, the fluid is being "added" to the system and "diffusing away" too, but unlike the 1st picture there is no advection.

I would like to know what might possibly cause this. Could this be because different vendors might be interpreting the standard differently?

PS : The "red" and "green" colors represent magnitude of vector-field in *x* and *y* directions respectively.

Comment: There can definitely be differences between IHV implementations. It could be due to a driver bug, or different interpretations of ambiguities in the standard, or even possibly differences in how the compilers treat floating-point arithmetic, etc. Would need some more detailed debugging to understand what's going on.

Comment: @NathanReed ,what kind of information could be helpful?

Comment: Start by debugging it like any other graphics/shader problem. Isolate each pass and see in which pass the error is being introduced, then isolate where in that shader is something going wrong.

Comment: This might be a vsync issue if you're using a variable timestep per-frame.

Comment: Are you using any vendor-dependent GLSL functions like noise*(which as far as I know, most vendors don't implement anyway)?

Comment: @Sam no. I am only using texture(). That shouldn't cause a problem, right?

Comment: @nilspin I don't think so. They're both running on the same OpenGL version, right?

Comment: @Sam yes they are.